# How to assess stationarity when kpss and dickey-fuller test give conflicting results?

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, kpss-test

I have used R to test the residuals of my time series data, I have used the tseries function for the kpss and dickey fuller test. Both gave conflicting results where dickey fuller said the data was stationary with p<0.01 and kpss said the data was not stationary with p<0.01. I also computed ndiff(data) for which it told me I needed to compute one difference to be stationary, however I was wondering if there was a more established way of determining if the data is stationary or not. For example another test?

Comment: ADF test is sensitive to trend/drift specification and the possible heteroscedasticity of the test residuals. In such cases, Phillips perron test can be a good nonparametric alternative to ADF.

Comment: These tests (kpss, adf) have opposite nulls and are famous for low power. Especially if there are near unit roots. I don't think there is an agreed on solution  except to say that you are not sure if its stationary or not. I have begun to wonder if just using the graphs of the data to decide if there is a trend is an alternative.

Comment: The Phillips perron test gives the same answer as the ADF test so unfortunately that leaves me back where I started

Comment: @user54285 I've been thinking that the graphs may be the best method of testing stationarity too. So far I've been looking at the acf plot and as it shows a very minor decline with most lags outside of the confidence interval I'm going to suggest that it is not stationary, is that correct? Do you know of any other graphs I could perhaps include?

Comment: I was making the general comment that you graph your raw time series and look if there is a trend in it or if the variance appears to change. I have others recommend this as well, although not as an alternative to formal tests.